# How do I use Azure Cognitive search's Knowledge Mining results and populate my Knowledge Base of my chatbot?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, chatbot, azure-cognitive-services, azure-bot-service

I m new to Azure, I need to make a chatbot that answers all types of questions pertaining to the data of SQL Database. I was thinking to use Azure Cognitive Search Knowledge Mining on this SQL DB and then somehow populating the Knowledge Base of the chatbot. How can I go about doing doing this?

Thanks. The least amount of code the better since I m only a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try [Information bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-scenario-informational?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) based on LUIS : Information Bot could answer questions defined in a knowledge set or FAQ using Cognitive Services QnA Maker and answer more open-ended questions by using Azure Search.

Often information is buried in structured data stores like SQL Server that can be easily surfaced via search. Imagine looking up a customer's order status by simple conversational commands. Using Cognitive Services QnA Maker, the user is presented with a set of valid search options like, lookup a customer, review a customer's most recent order, etc. With the QnA format defined the user can easily ask questions that are backed by Azure Search which can look up data stored in a SQL Database.

The structure is like following:
[image]

And sample bot is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureBotServices-scenarios